# Javascript how to push item into array that is stored in object

Tags: javascript

So I have an object:

```
var subDataMap = {count: 0, data: []};
```

And I tried insert a new empty array object into the data array stored in subDataMap:

```
subDataMap.data.push(new Array());
```

However it is not working as Javascript thinks push is a nested property inside subDataMap. As the error I get is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Comment: Add complete code. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: That error means that the .data property is undefined.

Comment: works fine for me... something else must be at play

Comment: Try `subDataMap.data[0].push(new Array());`. Although, little hard to tell what you're after exactly...

Comment: Your code is working fine man - https://jsfiddle.net/f6btjbgt/ - Just as @KeithNicholas said, must be something else going wrong. Please post your full code.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose You have an Array like this:

```
   var obj = {
              arrayOne: []

};
```

You can do like this:

```
var arrayLetters = ['x', 'y'];
obj.arrayOne.push(arrayLetters);
```